# Is there a way to test the RaiseChanged use of a property in MVVMLight?

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm-light

I have lots of properties in my viewmodels that have very little logic in them but they have the RaisePropertyChanged() method in them to refresh the GUI.  i.e.

```
private bool _StatesIsSelected;
public bool StatesIsSelected
{
    get { return _StatesIsSelected; }
    set
    {
        _StatesIsSelected = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("StatesIsSelected");
    }
}
```

I am starting to wonder if I should have unit tests confirming that the RaisePropertyChanged() method has been called.  If I forgot to put it in the property the GUI wouldn't get refreshed and the application would have a bug...so it should have a unit test.  But how do you test that?

So to sum it up....Am I being to militant about having unit tests for this logic?  And if I am not being to militant...what is there a good way to test for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you being militant? That is not really an easy question to answer. We do test the majority of our property changed events, of which there are a lot, and I'm not really sure how much value there is in those tests. By that I mean if we removed them and stopped writing them in the future would we start seeing more bugs, or even any that wouldn't be pretty obvious as soon as you used the client? To be honest the answer is probably no. Conversely they are easy tests to write and certainly don't hurt.

Anyway, yes there is a very nice way to do this (had to make a few minor tweeks, so can't guarantee the code will compile, but should make the concepts clear):

```
public static class PropertyChangedTestHelperFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Factory method for creating <see cref="PropertyChangedTestHelper{TTarget}"/> instances.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">
    /// The target.
    /// </param>
    /// <typeparam name="TTarget">
    /// The target type.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="PropertyChangedTestHelper{TTarget}"/>
    /// </returns>
    public static PropertyChangedTestHelper<TTarget> CreatePropertyChangedHelper<TTarget>(
        this TTarget target)
        where TTarget : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        return new PropertyChangedTestHelper<TTarget>(target);
    }
}

public sealed class PropertyChangedTestHelper<TTarget> : IDisposable
    where TTarget : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This list contains the expected property names that should occur in property change notifications
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Queue<string> propertyNames = new Queue<string>(); 

    /// <summary>
    /// The target of the helper
    /// </summary>
    private readonly TTarget target;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="StrictPropertyChangedTestHelper{TTarget}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
    public PropertyChangedTestHelper(TTarget target)
    {
        this.target = target;
        this.target.PropertyChanged += this.HandleTargetPropertyChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.target.PropertyChanged -= this.HandleTargetPropertyChanged;

        if (this.propertyNames.Count != 0)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Property change notification {0} was not raised", this.propertyNames.Peek());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets an expectation that a refresh change notification will be raised.
    /// </summary>
    public void ExpectRefresh()
    {
        this.propertyNames.Enqueue(string.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets an expectation that a property change notification will be raised.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">The type of the property.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertyExpression">The property expression.</param>
    public void Expect<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TTarget, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        this.propertyNames.Enqueue(((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member.Name);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the target property changed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="PropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void HandleTargetPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.propertyNames.Count == 0)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Unexpected property change notification {0}", e.PropertyName);
        }

        var expected = this.propertyNames.Dequeue();
        var propertyName = (e.PropertyName ?? string.Empty).Trim();
        if (propertyName != expected)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Out of order property change notification, expected '{0}', actual '{1}'", expected, propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[TestMethod]
public void StatesIsSelected_RaisesIsValidChangeNotification()
{
    // Arrange
    var target = new SomeViewModel();

    using (var helper = target.CreatePropertyChangedHelper())
    {
        helper.Expect(item => item.StatesIsSelected);

        // Act
        target.StatesIsSelected = true;

        // Assert
    }
}
```

When the helper is disposed the expectations are interrogated and the test will fail if they are not all met in the order they were defined.

We also have a **Weak** version that only requires that the expectations are met, not that they are met exactly (i.e. other property change events could be raised) and that is not order dependent.

FYI - if I were you I'd think about ditching MVVMLight and moving to Caliburn.Micro, its in a different league.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Caliburn.Micro comment?

Comment: Well, if you look at what MVVMLight actually does then the conclusion is not much and what it does is pretty clunky. The only problem it even attempts to solve is messaging, but Caliburn does that so much better. Yes, there is a view model base class, but you could write your own in a few hours. Caliburn does lots of cool stuff well, but the problem it actually needs to solve and does a pretty good job of is dynamic view resolution. That is what you need to do MVVM.

Comment: I will ask one more off-topic question of you...do you have any experience with ReactiveUI?  I believe it is based on Caliburn.Micro but adds reactive on top.

Comment: No I've not tried it. Looks good though. From looking at the documentation, the main problem that it is attempting to solve is enabling view state based on view model state in a testable way. That is a problem that caliburn doesn't really attempt. I see the threading thing as a bit of a non issue. The real problem is not initiating tasks on background threads, it is preventing deadlocks caused by your IoC contending on the main thread. There is no out of the box solution for that apart from experience and tuning. (non-issue is a bit harsh, just not the really nasty bit).

Comment: By the way, if you are writing XAML you might find this visual studio extension I've written useful: https://xamlr.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can test it easily:

```
void TestMethod()
{
   Container container = new Container();
   bool isRaised = false;
   container.PropertyChanged += (o,e) => { 
       if(e.PropertyName == "StatesIsSelected")
           isRaised = true;
       };
   container.StatesIsSelected = true;
   Assert.True(isRaised);
}
```

It think it would be useful to write the test for the ViewModel base class but not for all properties which raise a change, thats just too extreme

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment of 'too extreme'?

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting `.NET Framework >= 4.5` you can inherit from `ViewModelBase` and write helper method:

```
public class ViewModelBaseExtended : ViewModelBase
{

    protected void TryRaisePropertyChanged<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue,
                                             [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (oldValue == null || !oldValue.Equals(newValue))
        {
            oldValue = newValue;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

and your property code would look like that:

```
private bool _StatesIsSelected;
public bool StatesIsSelected
{
    get { return _StatesIsSelected; }
    set
    {
        TryRaisePropertyChanged(ref _StatesIsSelected, value);
    }
}
```

Now you would only have to assert property value in your unit tests.